# Accessing assigned variable items within combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I am using a `combobox` to add data to a `datagrid` with the coding below. What I want to achieve is accessing all of the '**item**' properties/information that's connected to that selected item's id and then setting all of that information to a class (**ExtraDisplayItems**). How would I go about doing this?

```
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;

    if (item != null)
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
```

Here is my class:

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

What I have gotten to work with databinding is displaying each of the item's 'id' in the datagrid and not any further.

**EDIT:** I am trying to use the same type that I used in my comboboxes, but I am having a bit of trouble.

I am just giving the extra information if it might help. Here is where I get all the information from my **WCF** service and then setting the information to my DisplayItems class in my **WPF** application:

```
private async Task LoadItems(TruckServiceClient TSC, QuoteOptionType type, ComboBox combobox)
{
    List<DisplayItems> displayItems = new List<DisplayItems>();
    foreach (var item in await TSC.GetQuoteOptionListAsync(type))
        displayItems.Add(new DisplayItems { Id = item.Key, Name = item.Value });
    combobox.ItemsSource = (displayItems.ToArray());
}
```

Then in the method below, I load the data from my *LoadItems* method into the specific comboboxes:

```
private async void QuoteWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.BodyType, cmbBodyType);
        ...
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.RearDropSide, cmbRearDropsideHeight);
        await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Extras, cmbAddExtras); //Extras
    }
    //cmbAddExtras.SelectionChanged += cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged;
}
```

In my final code snippet I am trying to set the `cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem` to my ***Type*** (wich I think is: `QuoteOptionType.Extras`).
I am trying to set the SelectedItem as below, but with no clue how to do it :(

```
var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as await QuoteOptionType.Extras;
```

or

```
var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as await LoadItems(TSC, QuoteOptionType.Extras, cmbAddExtras);
```

I am getting the errors:

> 'await' cannot be used as an identifier within an async method or
>   lamba expression
>   &
>
> ; expected
>
> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call  is complicated. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

As you can clearly see that I have **NO** clue what I am doing. Also here is my class where I create my `QuoteOptionType` class/enum. This is from my WCF application:

```
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum QuoteOptionType
{
    [EnumMember]
    BodyType,
    [EnumMember]
    Chassis,
    [EnumMember]
    PaintColor,
    [EnumMember]
    DropSide,
    [EnumMember]
    Floor,
    [EnumMember]
    RearDropSide,
    [EnumMember]
    Extras
}
```

**2nd EDIT:** Here I am using the Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetQuoteOptionList(QuoteOptionType optionType)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        switch (optionType)
        {
            case QuoteOptionType.BodyType:
                db.BodyTypes.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Name));
                break;
                ...
            case QuoteOptionType.RearDropSide:
                db.RearDropSides.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Name));
                break;
            case QuoteOptionType.Extras: // x.StockItem throws out the error: No overload for method  'Add' takes 3 arguments
                db.Extras.ToList().ForEach(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Description, x.StockItem)); 
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The option that was selected does not have a corresponding list.");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this code seems familiar ;)

Comment: @almulo Haha hey hey!

Comment: Ok, let's see... First of all, your `SelectedItem` returns always the same type of the items you've set in the `ItemsSource`. Since you've set a `List<DisplayItems>` as ItemsSource, then SelectedItem must be of type `DisplayItems`.

Comment: Then, you can't use `await` when casting types... `await` is used to perform a synchronous call to an `async` method. You're using it correctly in `QuoteWindow_Loaded`, but not when casting `SelectedItem`.

Comment: And finally, the `as` keyword for type casting expects a Type after it. `LoadItems(...)` is not a type, but a method call. And `QuoteOptionType.Extras` isn't a type either, but an `enum` value (`QuoteOptionType`, alone, is indeed a type... but not the correct one in this case)

Comment: I'll edit my answer according to the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is cast the `SelectedItem` to the appropiate type. For instance:

```
var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as DisplayItems;

if (item != null)
{
    var displayItem = new ExtraDisplayItems();
    displayItem.ItemId = item.Id;
    displayItem.ItemCode = GetCode(item);
    displayItem.ItemDescription = item.Name;

    DoStuffWithYourDisplayItem(displayItem);

    dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Even if `SelectedItem` returns an `object`, internally that object is actually your class (`DisplayItems`), so you can cast it and use it normally.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply almulo!  I am trying to do as you said, but having alot of issues with the 'type' of info in my comboboxes. Please see the EDIT that I posted in my question. It's very unorganized, but I do not know how to ask it in any other way.

Comment: Oky I see what you are doing and thank you AGAIN very very much for all of your effort and time almulo! :D I am getting somewhere! The only thing now is that in my `GetQuoteOptionList` method in my WCF app, I can only set the` (x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Description));` and not add another "`(x => result.Add(x.Id, x.Description, x.StockItem))`". I am using a Dictionary in my IService in my WCF application. I've posted an 2nd EDIT in my answer :P

Comment: I guess that should go in a THIRD post, since it's a different question haha But the thing is that Dictionaries only store two values: key and value. If you want to store more info, one of those two (the value, usually) should be of some `struct` type that stores two or more values inside. So it would be something like `(x => result.Add(x.Id, new ExtraValues { Description = x.Description, StockItem = x.StockItem }))`... Look for info about `struct` and how to create your `ExtraValues` one ;)

Comment: Oky I will look into that. Thanks alot almulo! :)

Comment: Hi almulo :) I know this is extremely random, but I do remember you helping me on seperate questions so far and I know from your profile that you specialize in WPF and UI. I am in **dire** need of assistance and seeing as there is no way to PM you  I need to do it like this. If you have ANY time, can you please have a look at this question of mine [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138374/adding-data-only-to-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid). No one has commented or answered on my question so far. I might seem desperate for doing this, but I really am desperate for help

Comment: So only if have the time to spare please help me. I would appreciate it very very much! :D