# Adding data only to a specific Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to find a way to add data from one datagrid to another and for that data to be inserted to only one column at a time in my second datagrid. The specific column is created each time the `Add` button has been clicked.

My coding so far:

```
private void btnFeedbackAddSupplier_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Items.Clear(); //So that my rows do not stack each other on every add

    DataGridTextColumn columnSupplier = new DataGridTextColumn();
    columnSupplier.Binding = new Binding("Supplier");
    DataGridTextColumn columnFeedbackSupplierItem = new DataGridTextColumn();
    //The 'Item' column is binded in XAML
    columnSupplier.Header = (cmbFeedbackSelectSupplier.SelectedItem as DisplayItems).Name;
    columnSupplier.IsReadOnly = true;

    dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectAll(); //Selects all the rows in 1st datagrid

    //Casts selected rows to my 'ViewQuoteItemList' class
    IList list = dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectedItems as IList;
    IEnumerable<ViewQuoteItemList> items = list.Cast<ViewQuoteItemList>();

    var collection = (from i in items let a = new ViewQuoteItemList { Item = i.Item, Supplier = i.Cost }
                          select a).ToList();

    //Adds both the column and data to the 2nd datagrid
    dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Columns.Add(columnSupplier);
    foreach (var item in collection)
        dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Items.Add(item);
}
```

My reason for wanting to add the data to only one separate column at a time is because the data is different each time I want to add it to my 2nd datagrid and it overwrites any previous data that was entered in older add's.

**EDIT**: I Here are some images of what my current problem is

Here I add the first company and it's values. Everything works fine
[image: First image]

Here I add the second company with it's new values, **but it changes the values entered with the first company**. This is my big problem. So you can see how my values are changed from the first to the second image

[image]

Comment: It seems like you want to make the column header dynamic, is it? In that case, then the previous columns should be deleted: then you add new `item` every time. likewise your `Rows`

Comment: But I am not sure what do you mean by "only to specific column" in your title. Because if what you want is to put data only to specific column, then the name of the column (or some other alternative info like index of the column) must be known before hand. Thus when you put the data, you can put the data specifically on that columns. Perhaps image/diagram of what you expect to happen would be very helpful to explain your need here...

Comment: To clear the columns, use `Columns.Clear` and for rows `Rows.Clear`

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for having a look at my problem Ian. I appreciate it very very much! :) I have updated my question so you can maybe have a better idea of what i'm doing

Comment: ur question is not clear. try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I'm adding data from one datagrid(1st) to another datagrid(2nd), but the `Cost` changes in my 1st datagrid every time I add the data to my 2nd datagrid. So i'm asking how can I add the new data to a new column, without it changing the previous data that was added previously. This is better explained in my pictures

Comment: @CareTaker22 Create a Binding between the Cost in the data-sources of your 2 DGrids.

Comment: Do you mean that I should create a binding between the two datagrid's `Cost` columns?

Comment: @CareTaker22 thanks for the image update. The question is getting clearer at least, but there are some doubts remain still. Let me try to put it with a scenario. Suppose now you have Columns A and B with data set setA and setB for Column A & B respectively. When you click the button, **what could be the possible case**? (1) It is always new Columns added, but no old Columns will be deleted (like what you show), (2) It is possible to have no new Column at all, just change the data in the old Column, (3) Both 1 & 2, (4) It is possible that the column B is **replace** with Column C with setC.

Comment: @Ian no problem man and thank you for still helping me out! :) For the scenario, it's definitely nr. 1 (case 1). There is always a new company being added on the button click. **What I left out is:** I update the prices for all the items in datagrid one and then select the company to whom those prices belong to and then add the company + prices to the second datagrid. It's kind of setting prices for each company and then selecting what company would be best to use, according to their prices for all the items.

Comment: So you basically compare the prices of all the companies next to each other and choose the cheapest one.

Comment: Hi! :) I think your problem here is that all your columns are bound to the same property: `Supplier`. Since you're updating that property everytime, all columns are assigned the same value. In the end, there's only one Supplier property for each row, so you can't show a different value for that single property on each column since everytime you change that property's value, the Bindings get notified and update themselves.

Comment: @CareTaker22 I am on my holiday now and too bad that my laptop isn't with me till 11 Feb. :( I can only comment for now. In that case, you may need to create new Column every time and to create new data to be inserted to the new cells in the new column. And the creation of the new data depends on your data type. If your data type is reference type like class, then Clone of the data it refers to may be needed. Will see when I got my laptop back. But hope you may also get good solution before hand, in case you need the solution quickly.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much for sticking with me man! I appreciate your help and advice very much and the time you put into trying to understand my weird questions ;P I will keep on trying different things for my question, but for now the answer below helped me out. I hope you enjoy your vacation a lot!!

Comment: @CareTaker22 great! Glad that your problem has been solved. Thanks... ;) Though I am in vacation, I cannot help but occasionally checking SO - to find questions which I can answer without code for testing. Apparently, it is not that easy.. for I tend to miss a couple of things... But your case seems to be impossible for me not to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem here is that all your columns are bound to the same property: `Supplier`. Since you're updating that property everytime, all columns are assigned the same value. In the end, there's only one Supplier property for each row, so you can't show a different value for that single property on each column since everytime you change that property's value, the Bindings get notified and update themselves.

Maybe you could try using a `OneTime` Binding instead of a regular one. That way, the cells would retain the value they had when you first added them to the DataGrid. But for that to work, you should avoid clearing the DataGrid's items list, since re-adding the items would force them to rebind again.

Another option would be having a list of suppliers in your Supplier property, and have each column bind to an index of that list.

```
private void btnFeedbackAddSupplier_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{

    // ...        

    columnSupplier.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("Supplier[{0}]", supplierColumnIndex));

    // ...

    var supplierCosts = new List<int>();

    // ...
    // Fill the list with the Costs of the Suppliers that correspond to each column and item
    // ...

    var collection = (from i in items let a = new ViewQuoteItemList { Item = i.Item, Supplier = supplierCosts }
                          select a).ToList();

    //Adds both the column and data to the 2nd datagrid
    dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Columns.Add(columnSupplier);
    foreach (var item in collection)
        dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Items.Add(item); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much almulo! It gave me a new perspective on how to approach my problem and to get past it. :) Learning something new every day